# How to serialize `LastEvaluatedKey` from DynamoDB's Golang SDK?

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

When working with DynamoDB in Golang, if a call to `query` has more results, it will set `LastEvaluatedKey` on the `QueryOutput`, which you can then pass in to your next call to `query` as `ExclusiveStartKey` to pick up where you left off.

This works great when the values stay in Golang. However, I am writing a paginated API endpoint, so I would like to serialize this key so I can hand it back to the client as a pagination token. Something like this, where `something` is the magic package that does what I want:

```golang
type GetDomainObjectsResponse struct {
  Items     []MyDomainObject `json:"items"`
  NextToken string           `json:"next_token"`
}
  
func GetDomainObjects(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  // ... parse query params, set up dynamoIn ...

  dynamoIn.ExclusiveStartKey = something.Decode(params.NextToken)

  dynamoOut, _ := db.Query(dynamoIn)

  response := GetDomainObjectsResponse{}
  dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalListOfMaps(dynamoOut.Items, &response.Items)

  response.NextToken := something.Encode(dynamoOut.LastEvaluatedKey)
  
  // ... marshal and write the response ...
}
```

(please forgive any typos in the above, it's a toy version of the code I whipped up quickly to isolate the issue)

Because I'll need to support several endpoints with different search patterns, I would love a way to generate pagination tokens that doesn't depend on the specific search key.

The trouble is, I haven't found a clean and generic way to serialize the `LastEvaluatedKey`. You can marshal it directly to JSON (and then e.g. base64 encode it to get a token), but doing so is not reversible. `LastEvaluatedKey` is a `map[string]types.AttributeValue`, and `types.AttributeValue` is an interface, so while the json encoder can read it, it can't write it.

For example, the following code panics with `panic: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type types.AttributeValue`.

```golang
lastEvaluatedKey := map[string]types.AttributeValue{
    "year":  &types.AttributeValueMemberN{Value: "1993"},
    "title": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: "Benny & Joon"},
}

bytes, err := json.Marshal(lastEvaluatedKey)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

decoded := map[string]types.AttributeValue{}
err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &decoded)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
```

What I would love would be a way to use the DynamoDB-flavored JSON directly, like [what you get when you run `aws dynamodb query` on the CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html). Unfortunately [the golang SDK doesn't support this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/issues/134).

I suppose I could write my own serializer / deserializer for the AttributeValue types, but that's more effort than this project deserves.

Has anyone found a generic way to do this?

Comment: You should be able to use `dynamodbattribute` package to marshal/unmarshal those

Comment: Hi @BurakSerdar. AFAICT the `Marshal`/`Unmarshal` funcitons of the `dynamodbattribute` package allows you to convert an `AttributeValue` to a go struct, but you need to have a struct to unmarshal to. That means you need to know the structure of `LastEvaluatedKey`, and it means the same solution won't work for different search keys.

Comment: You can unmarshal to an interface{}

Comment: `dynamodbattribute.Unmarshal` does take an `interface{}`, but you still need to have a concrete type somewhere. [The example in the docs for Unmarshal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/#Unmarshal) shows this - they create a struct at the top, then pass it in. The fields in that struct need to match the structure of your `AttributeValue`, which will be different depending on your search key. I would like to avoid creating a different struct for each possible search.

Comment: @blackgreen Interesting idea, but our servers are replicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I figured something out.

```golang
type GetDomainObjectsResponse struct {
  Items     []MyDomainObject `json:"items"`
  NextToken string           `json:"next_token"`
}
  
func GetDomainObjects(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  // ... parse query params, set up dynamoIn ...

  eskMap := map[string]string{}
  json.Unmarshal(params.NextToken, &eskMap)
  esk, _ = dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(eskMap)
  dynamoIn.ExclusiveStartKey = esk

  dynamoOut, _ := db.Query(dynamoIn)

  response := GetDomainObjectsResponse{}
  dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalListOfMaps(dynamoOut.Items, &response.Items)

  lek := map[string]string{}
  dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(dynamoOut.LastEvaluatedKey, &lek)
  response.NextToken := json.Marshal(lek)
  
  // ... marshal and write the response ...
}
```

(again this is my real solution hastily transferred back to the toy problem, so please forgive any typos)

As @buraksurdar pointed out, `attributevalue.Unmarshal` takes an `inteface{}`. Turns out in addition to a concrete type, you can pass in a `map[string]string`, and it just works.

I believe this will NOT work if the `AttributeValue` is not flat, so this isn't a general solution [citation needed]. But my understanding is the `LastEvaluatedKey` returned from a call to `Query` will always be flat, so it works for this usecase.

Comment: I think we should use map[string]interface{}{} because I believe there can be numeric indexes as well within dynamoOut.LastEvaluatedKey..

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Dan, here is a solution to serialize and deserialize to/from base64

```
package dynamodb_helpers

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/json"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/attributevalue"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/types"
)

func Serialize(input map[string]types.AttributeValue) (*string, error) {
    var inputMap map[string]interface{}
    err := attributevalue.UnmarshalMap(input, &inputMap)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    bytesJSON, err := json.Marshal(inputMap)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    output := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(bytesJSON)
    return &output, nil
}

func Deserialize(input string) (map[string]types.AttributeValue, error) {
    bytesJSON, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(input)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    outputJSON := map[string]interface{}{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(bytesJSON, &outputJSON)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return attributevalue.MarshalMap(outputJSON)
}
```

Comment: I believe that we should improve this solution by adding a secret and encrypting it with a key to avoid security vulnerabilities . Please check this: https://github.com/supersoniko/dynamodb-paginator#security-disclaimer

Comment: https://github.com/blaskovicz/go-cryptkeeper this library should solve the encryption and decryption problem

Comment: good idea, I will check how to do it without a third party library

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Dan and ThomasP1988 I would like to give a quick solution by merging above inputs. Heres how you can implement pagination in your API using LastEvaluatedKey and ExclusiveStartKey in GoLang and DynamoDb

```
// getting lsk map from base64 string
    var esk map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue
    if lastEvaluatedKey != "" {
        bytesJSON, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(lastEvaluatedKey)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to decode lek : %w", err)
        }
        var outputJSON map[string]interface{}
        err = json.Unmarshal(bytesJSON, &outputJSON)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal lek : %w", err)
        }
        esk, err = dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(outputJSON)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal lek : %w", err)
        }
    }
// you need to pass this in your Query input with limit
result, err := s.db.Query(
    &dynamodb.QueryInput{
        TableName:                 aws.String("TableName"),
        IndexName:                 aws.String("IndexName"),
        ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
        KeyConditionExpression:    expr.KeyCondition(),
        ScanIndexForward:          aws.Bool(false),
        ExclusiveStartKey:         esk,
        Limit:                     aws.Int64(10),
    },
)


// returning LastEvaluatedKey as base 64 encoded string
    lekOutPut := ""
    if result.LastEvaluatedKey != nil {
        lek := map[string]interface{}{}
        dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.LastEvaluatedKey, &lek) //put last evaluated key in a map
        lastKey, err := json.Marshal(lek)                             // convert to byte array
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal lek : %w", err)
        }
        lekOutPut = base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(lastKey) //convert to string to return as a param
    }
```

return lekOutPut in response to client so that client can send it back to you in another API req